# Boilerplate to develop web components

Tags: polymer, web-component

I was looking at the repositories of PolymerLab and I met this repository:

https://github.com/PolymerLabs/untitled-element

This repository seem to serve as a boilerplate to create web components, but when I open the guide from the README file, I read a documentation that talks about other repository:

https://github.com/PolymerLabs/seed-element

and I was wondering, what is it? In untitled-element outdated? Or is it an error in the documentation?

Could maybe someone explain me the difference between this 2 boilerplates to start web component development?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for the confusion.

`untitled-element` is a minimal version created by the Polymer Engineering team specifically to provide a sample of our version of the canonical element repository.

`seed-element` has more features and was built by the Polymer Developer Relations folks to provide a nicer on-ramp.

You could use either one, depending on whether your prefer a minimal or turnkey approach.

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up, Scott :) Dont you think that the "guide" on the README file for "untitled-element" should talk about it, instead of talking about "seed-element"? I hope you change that ;)

Comment: Yes, this is just a mistake that manifested when `seed-element` was born. Thanks for the heads up.